# Can I change the name of the file used by MVC to display detail data in my grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code that I use to display detail rows in a grid:

```
 foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item)
        }
```

My model is a collection of `IList<ContentDetail>` and this uses the

> Shared > DisplayTemplates > ContentDetail.cshtml file when it displays the items.

Is it possible for me to make it so that it uses a different file? I would like to have more than 
one way of displaying the details and so I need to have more than one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the Intellisense in Visual Studio, the `@Html.DisplayFor` and `@Html.DisplayForModel` both can take a `string TemplateName` as an overload, where the TemplateName is the name of a partial view used to render that property or collection.  The correct syntax would be:

```
@Html.DisplayForModel("MyTemplateToUse")
```

or

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>item, "MyTemplateToUse")
```

This should allow you to use a different file to render out your stuffs.